# How to use Corba with Python

Tags: python, corba

I'm wondering if anyone have a good resource for working with Corba in Python? I've googled around and saw that fnorb was recommended by some, but that it doesn't support some new features in Corba. Omniorb seemed like a good alternative, but I have no idea how to use it with Python (not fnorb either).

Any advice is appreciated, I've only implemented some simple examples in Java before so my understanding of Corba is sparse.

Thanks!

Comment: `fnorb` is the one I ended up using with full satisfaction -- but that was years ago, so my use didn't test the "new features" you need.  Do you have a specific list of those needed "features newer than fnorb" or better yet a precise identification of the Corba version you must support?

Comment: Fnorb came to mind immediately as well, but the web presence is looking a bit cobwebby - fnorb.org appears to be owned by a domain squatter.  Is it still being maintained by anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with the omniORBpy [User's Guide](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omnipy3/omniORBpy/) ?

Comment: +1 omniORBpy is a very good implementation of CORBA for Python.